# Jquery draggable detect position function merge together

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(function(){
        $( "#layer_1" ).draggable({
            drag: function(){
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                var xPos = offset.left;
                var yPos = offset.top;

                $('#layer1_posX').val(xPos);
                $('#layer1_posY').val(yPos);
            }
        });

        $( "#layer_2" ).draggable({
            drag: function(){
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                var xPos = offset.left;
                var yPos = offset.top;

                $('#layer2_posX').val(xPos);
                $('#layer2_posY').val(yPos);
            }
        });
    });
```

I have 2 div using jquery draggable and calculate position. How to merge 2 `$().draggable();` function together?

(if I have 2 or more draggable elements, I don't need to keep repeat the code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found solution, place input next to element

```
$( "#layer_1, #layer_2" ).draggable({
    drag: function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;

        $(this).next('.x').val(xPos);
        $(this).next().next('.y').val(yPos);
    }
});
```